# Find the volume integral of the function $f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ over:

Tags: multivariable-calculus

a) the region given by $0 \leq x \leq 1, 1 \leq y \leq 2, 0 \leq z \leq 3$,
b) the region inside the sphere of radius $R$ centred on the origin

For a) the first thing I've done is convert the function to spherical coordinates,  $\Rightarrow f = r^2$, so:
$$
\iiint f\mathrm{d}V = \iiint r^4 sin(\Phi)\mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\Phi \mathrm{d}\theta,
$$
which is simple enough to integrate, however I am not sure about the limits.
Using the bounds of $x,y,z$ I can gather that $1 \leq f \leq 14$, but I don't think this is useful at all.

For b), I am very unsure about how to do this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For question a, it is better to use artesian coordinate:

$$\int_0^1\int_1^2\int_0^1(x^2 +y^2 + z^2)dzdydx = 17$$

For question b, we can use spherical coordinates:

$$\int_0^R\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}r^4cos{\phi}d{\theta}d{\phi}dr = \frac{4\pi}{5}R^5$$